# .mouseenter() issue in Microsoft Edge on touch screen enabled devices

Tags: jquery, css, microsoft-edge

I have SlimMenu on a website and I noticed that using Microsoft Edge on touch screen enabled devices, with SlimMenu navbar in full width mode (not mobile toggle button mode) when you try to tap on the small arrow down next to the menu items, the dropdown will slideDown and slideUp back immediately.

At first I thought it was a SlimMenu issue, BUT on all other browsers it works as expected (even in Explorer 11), moreover the same issue is reproducible at the same way with [FlexNav](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-Touch-Friendly-jQuery-Menu-Plugin-Flexnav/).

I guess that has something to do on how Edge browser handles .mouseenter() and .mouseleave() actions.

**To replicate the issue:**

- Windows 10
- Microsoft Edge
- A touch screen enabled device

Then go to SlimMenu page: http://adnantopal.github.io/slimmenu/ (in the middle of the page you have a demo of the menu, try it in full width mode).

So does anybody know if there's a workaround for this?

Comment: So what does it making it to collapse? Mouseout? You may want to use another type of slim menu. Check http://cr8code.co and at the nav bar there is a three dot menü at right top corner check if it is useful for you then i shere the code for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help  Güney. But I solved the issue by myself (see answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was right. It has to do on how Microsoft Edge browser handles .mouseenter() and .mouseleave().

In fact they should NOT propagate to child elements, BUT in Edge they do.

To solve the issue I had to manually stop the propagation from "li" to "span":

```
$("span").mouseenter(function(event){
event.stopPropagation();  
});
```